# Spring oauth2 - authorization code deleted after consumed

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

maybe i'm misunderstanding the authorization code grant type, but i thought that after issuing a code spring will keep the code in oauth_code table in DB forever till it will be revoked by user , but the code is deleted right after it is consumed (first time you exchange this for token),

so what is the flow here - should my clients keep the refresh tokens for getting access token later on (or when user is offline)

the spec say the return of refresh tokens is optional as written

> *The authorization server authenticates the client, validates the
>           authorization code, and ensures that the redirection URI
>           received matches the URI used to redirect the client in
>           step (C).  If valid, the authorization server responds back with
>           an access token and, optionally, a refresh token.*

so it the authorization server decide not to give refresh token there is no way for clients to offline request access token and they need to go though the authorization code process all over again ?

thanks
Shlomi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization code can only be used once, and it must have a short lifetime. If you read section 4.1.2 of the spec it says

> The authorization code MUST expire
>     shortly after it is issued to mitigate the risk of leaks.  A
>     maximum authorization code lifetime of 10 minutes is
>     RECOMMENDED.

So once a code has been used there is not real reason to retain it (other than possibly to detect further attempts to use it).

The refresh token allows the client to obtain another access token. Otherwise, as you say, it needs to re-execute the authorization code flow to get one from scratch, which requires the interaction of the resource owner (the user). Usually the system would be set up to issue a refresh token or not to that client depending on whether it actually requires offline access to the resource, or whether the resource owner (user) will always be interating with it directly.

Comment: Thanks, now i saw that refresh token also has expiration (longer than access but still) , so we say that the  in case of offline access is needed - the client will always go through authorization request again. now since probably the provider keep previous approvals this will be transparent ?

Comment: The expiration of both access tokens and refresh tokens is configurable, so you can set it to something suitable. There's nothing to stop the client managing the tokens so that it asks for a new one before the refresh token expires. If the approval is stored then the user shouldn't have to re-approve the same authorization (unless you them to). Generally they would also be given control over previous approvals and could delete them if they wish.

Comment: just double checking i understand you - we need this for offline access. lets say the refresh token expire in one week , then the client would need to go through the auth code flow (which requires user login) and the user is not there. so you say the client should ask for refresh token every day (for example) to avoid its complete expiration ?

Comment: Clients don't "ask for a refresh token". They use one to request a new access token, and may receive a new replacement refresh token in the process. The lifetime of the refresh token will typically be much longer, however it's up to you to choose something that makes sense. For example, if you know the client will need access once a day, you could make your access tokens valid for a day and the refresh tokens expire weekly.

Comment: hi - i think there is a bug in spring as its not creating new refresh token , i have set my client to 60 seconds of refresh token validity , and after that time the refresh token is expired and exception is thrown. i also saw some contradiction in the code DefaultTokenServices createAccessToken check if the refresh token expired and create new one but this code never been called since the RefreshTokenGranter is checking for expired token and (through DefaultTokenServices.refreshAcessToken) throws an exception. did someone saw spring is giving new refresh token when access token is requested ?

Comment: This isn't really directly related to your original question, and SO comments aren't really big enough to describe new problems adequately. If you think there's a bug then you should report it in the project's issue tracker. Either that or put together another question clearly stating what you've done, providing your configuration and explaining what happens.

Comment: i did that in another opened issue for immortal refesh tokens - Dave opened this for 2.0.6 milestone.